# Shading issue when using bevels

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make this bevel work on a curved surface but the n-gon it creates produces some really bad shading which cannot be ignored. Basically what I had was a subdivided mesh (already applied sub-d) in which I wanted to add further detail to. I selected some faces and extruded it inwards along the normals and then I beveled the end to make it curved. I have tried connecting some vertices and attempting a grid fill but the shading issue still remains. Any advice on how to fix this? [image]

[image]

Here is the file to this specific part : [image]

Comment: I might try insetting a face in that n-gon at the tip of the groove. Just a tiny margin around it, about the size of a bevel segment, to point the averaged normals in the right direction.

Comment: @TheLabCat still can't seem to get it :( I've attached the file if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You have a big ngon with stretched triangles, if you create these edges it will help to avoid these artefacts:

[image]

Comment: This still caused some shading issues, lots of pinching all around. I found another solution which involves transferring the normal data and it turned out fine. Here's a video on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZXYWzv02m4&list=PLXa36kw-c-sx9fKWiQJVb550G1qP7VVOQ&index=77&t=365s

Comment: yes that's a good idea